# install nodejs with mongodb and node js run but mongo db establish connect test and then some error network failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

install nodejs with mongodb and node js run but mongo db establish connect test and then some error network failed

```
$ mongo
```

> errno:10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

[image]

Comment: Please post the error message in the question instead of the image

Comment: @gvmani  it doesn't really matter the error message is very straightforward. The problem and answer too.

Comment: Just a [personal] suggestion: Use Ubuntu/Linux Mint for development, specially web, it makes life a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1):

Your using the wrong executable.  Instead  of `mongo` use `mongod` - it starts the mongo server. `mongo` is for  editing/adding stuff to the database from the console. You don't need it. For node all you need is `mongod`

Example: `cd mongodb` > `mongod`

If error message comes up about data/db not set, add a folder called `data` with a subfolder `db` in `C/`